# Create pandas dataframe from JSON object with diffrent column names and number of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a JSON object like bellow.

```
{
        'id': "email@gmail.com",
        'item': ['abc', 1],  # name, id
        'supply': '23FEG',
        'price': [[1, 100], [2, 150], [5, 400]],  # quantity, price
}
```

In the above JSON, there can be multiple values for price and I want to create a data frame such that it will include all the price values uniquely and populate the rest of the columns with the same values.

In addition to that, the column name of data frames will be different

Expected output :

```
email              item_name   supply   quantity  price  
                                            
email@gmail.com     abc         23FEG     1         100
email@gmail.com     abc         23FEG     2         150
email@gmail.com     abc         23FEG     5         400
```

Comment: Please add some code of your attempts at solving the problem to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how other items will be added to your JSON you will need to import your data with the correct `orient` parameter.

For your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient="index")
df = df.T.explode('price')
df['item'] = pd.Series(df['item'].to_list()[0])
df[['quantity', 'price']] = pd.DataFrame(df['price'].to_list(), index= df.index)
print(df.rest_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
                id item supply  price  quantity
0  email@gmail.com  abc  23FEG    100         1
1  email@gmail.com  abc  23FEG    150         2
2  email@gmail.com  abc  23FEG    400         5
```